# HTML anchor tag's download attribute's optional new filename for the downloaded file is not working

Tags: html, href, anchor

I have written the following HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="../../../media/jupiter" download="big_planet"> Click here to download the file </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the link instead of the downloaded file having the name of `big_planet` has the name `jupiter`. I tried it in multiple browsers and they all give the downloaded file name as jupiter instead of big_planet.

Can someone please tell the reason and suggest me a solution?

Comment: `download` is merely a suggestion to the browser; the browser is free to ignore it. Have you tried this in multiple browsers?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yes I tried it in multiple browsers and they all give the downloaded file name as jupiter instead of big_planet.